# Eloquent delete all rows with where statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to delete all the votes where the flag "isOnly" is true which means the article is voted before the plenary session.

I have this code written, which deletes ALL the votes.

```
    foreach($commision->articles as $article) {
        $article->votes()->delete();
        $article->update([
            'isVoted' => false
        ]);
    }
```

What is the right way to delete all the votes with the flag 'isOnly' == true

Comment: what is the structure of $commission->articles, is isOnly a direct key inside the collection itself, show `dd($commission->articles);`, you can use forget() along with filter()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stack where methods with delete call

```
$article->votes()->where('isOnly', true)->delete();
```

One better solution would be to avoid the foreach all together so you run only one query

```
$articleIds = $commision->pluck('articles.id'); //if the articles are already loaded calling a collection method pluck()
$articleIds = $commision->articles()->pluck('id'); // if articles are not loaded calling a query builder method pluck()
Votes::whereHas('article', function($articleQueryBuilder) use($articleIds) {
    $articleQueryBuilder->whereIn('id', $articleIds);
})->where('isOnly', true)->delete();
Article::whereIn('id', $articleIds)->update([
    'isVoted' => false
]);
```

This will result in a faster processing of your delete() & update().

Comment: Just to explain what this query do, when you do `votes()` you are still using `Eloquent`, so any further `where` or similar method, will be appended/added to the `votes()` query.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really helpful.

Comment: @Steve corrected some errors and two solutions to get the articles ids

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way to delete by condition

```
$article->votes()->get()->filter(function($item){
     return $item->isOnly == true;
})->each(function($vote){$vote->delete();});
```

This statement will get all votes and apply **filter** funtion on votes which will give us votes which has **isOnly == true** rows. Then **each** function will delete returned votes.
This will help. :)

Comment: That's even worst that the foreach OP used. Let's say each commission has 10 articles, and each article has 100 votes. Your solution will run 1000 queries. OP solution will run 10. The article id solution will only run 2 queries no matter how many votes per article and article per commission.

Comment: I said this is one way of deleting. I didn't say its only way. Second sql still goes through all rows. Also if isOnly is indexed it will then take less load on sql server.

Comment: There is a big difference between a query that deletes 1000 rows and 1000 query that deletes 1 row at a time. The difference from 50millisecond query to 2 minutes for the 1000 query (with index). You need to learn more about performance.